# Is it possible to intercept the sami api call twice WHEN loading a webpage in Cypress?

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, cypress, alias

I am trying to intercept an API call twice (with different body) ( with aliasing and using the cypress wait method) WHEN loading a web page.
I've noticed that it only calls the second intercept twice.
Is there a built-in solution in cypress that we can use to intercept the same api call twice when loading a Webpage?

```js
cy.intercept('POST', '/SomeUrl', {
    statusCode: 200,
    fixture: 'jsonname.json',
    times: 1,
    }).as('alias');
cy.intercept('POST', '/SomeUrl', {
    statusCode: 200,
    fixture: 'jsonname2.json',
    times: 1,
    }).as('alias2');

cy.visit('https://www.url.com')
   .wait('@alias')
   .wait('@alias2')
```

The Routes output in the Cypress UI shows us this result:

| Method | URL | Stubbed | Alias | # |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| POST | **/SomeUrl | Yes | alias | - |
| POST | **/SomeUrl | Yes | alias2 | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for an array of aliases (https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait#Aliases).

So you could try the following code.

```
cy.visit('https://www.url.com')
cy.wait(['@alias', '@alias2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's solved with:

```
cy.intercept('POST', '/SomeUrl', (req) => {
     if (req.body.Objectstatus === 1) {
     req.reply({
         statusCode: 200,
         fixture: 'alias.json',
     });
}
     if (req.body.Objectstatus  === 1) {
         req.reply({
         statusCode: 200,
         fixture: 'alias2.json',
     });
     }
   }).as('alias');
});
```